Supabase integration with swift. Issue with "Extra trailing closure passed in call" error message
I am trying to create a Function to fetch conversations for a user in SwiftUIachat app frontend to a Supabase db instance. Unfortunately, Xcode produces the following error message: "Extra trailing closure passed in call" when I declare the func fetchConversations that you will find below.
I would be grateful for any help.
import Foundation
import Supabase

class SupabaseManager {
    static let shared = SupabaseManager()

    let client: SupabaseClient

    private init() {
        let supabaseUrl = URL(string: "https://mysite.supabase.co")! // Replace with your Supabase URL
        let supabaseKey = "supabaseKey" // Replace with your Supabase public API key
        self.client = SupabaseClient(supabaseURL: supabaseUrl, supabaseKey: supabaseKey)
    }

    func registerWithPhone(email: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (Result<User, Error>) -> Void) {
            Task {
                do {
                    let authResponse = try await client.auth.signUp(email: email, password: password)
                    let user = authResponse.user
                    completion(.success(user))
                } catch {
                    completion(.failure(error))
                }
            }
        }

        func loginWithPhone(email: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (Result<User, Error>) -> Void) {
            Task {
                do {
                    let authResponse = try await client.auth.signIn(email: email, password: password)
                    let user = authResponse.user
                    completion(.success(user))
                } catch {
                    completion(.failure(error))
                }
            }
        }

        func logout(completion: @escaping (Result<Void, Error>) -> Void) {
            Task {
                do {
                    try await client.auth.signOut()
                    completion(.success(()))
                } catch {
                    completion(.failure(error))
                }
            }
        }
        
    // Function to fetch conversations for a user
    func fetchConversations(for userId: UUID, completion: @escaping (Result<[Conversation], Error>) -> Void) {
        client.database
            .from("Chats")
            .select("chat_id, created_by, created_at")
            .eq("created_by", value: userId.uuidString)
            .execute { result in
                switch result {
                case .success(let response):
                    do {
                        let conversations = try JSONDecoder().decode([Conversation].self, from: response.data)
                        completion(.success(conversations))
                    } catch {
                        completion(.failure(error))
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    completion(.failure(error))
                }
            }
    }

}

I have tried re-formulate the func declaration without any luck.
Any help would be great.
Many thanks

A quick look at the documentation tells me you should use try await also when fetching data so no need for that closure at all. And you should really embrace async/await completely and remove all use of completion handlers in your code. documentation I looked at

That worked great. Thanks a million Jokim
